# "Windows must now restart because the power service terminated unexpectedly"

Tags: windows, reboot

Just had this dialog box appear on a few day old Windows 7 i5 laptop. No bloatware, no malware, antivirus running.. I've never seen this message before. The only button was 'close', which didn't actually do anything. I restarted the laptop to be on the safe side, and all drivers are at their latest versions.

Googling doesn't really turn up anything beyond the general 'run virus scans' etc. Does anyone have any idea what this actually means - what is the power service, why would it stop, why would Windows need to restart?

Thanks.

Comment: It has to do with Windows Power Management. Has this error occurred more than once? What brand and model of laptop? Are all the Windows Updates installed? Any BIOS updates? Are there any error messages in Event Viewer or Device Manager?

Comment: Occurred just once, HP Probook 650 G1, Windows fully updated, BIOS updated- I will have to check Event Viewer but Device Manager is all fine.

Comment: Obviously, Windows recognized something went wrong and corrected it. If it has only happened once, I'm not sure it is technically a problem. If it were to continue to occur, then it is a problem needing to be answered.

Comment: I get this error or "Windows must now restart because the DCOM service process launcher terminated unexpectedly" within a minute of starting up this laptop. Everything I've read is run-this or run-that, but guess what, the message pops up and restarts my computer before anything can be done. Any suggestions?

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Windows on this week old laptop and it seems to have resolved the issue. I guess that it was a driver issue, even though drivers were all updated with HP Softpaq.